# How to get a link to download videos on Twitter in all sizes in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, twitter

I apply node.js to download videos from social media sites and I was able to download videos from YouTube and Facebook but I could not do this via Twitter.

Some libraries have already used the node but have not worked